# Not enough of these objects was/were?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is "Not enough of these objects were available" correct, or should it be "was available"? I think the former sounds correct, but if I omit "of these objects" then I tend towards "was".

Comment: Enough is enough; not 'enough are enough'!

Answer (score 1):

In general, "enough" is used countably with countable objects and uncountably with uncountable objects.

*Are there enough teaspoons?*

*Is there enough sugar?*

---

**Examples**

1.

*Q: Do we have a sufficient amount of cement?*

*A: Yes, there is enough for the whole patio.*

2.

*Q: There are lots of people coming. How are we for wineglasses?*

*A: There are enough to go around.*

---

**Note**

You may occasionally see an apparent exception but this can be explained by the underlying grammar.

Comment: Thank you. So "were" is correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct  because objects are countable. This is confirmed by the fact that the word "objects" is in the plural.